# Partial differential equation of a function with multiple dependencies

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, chain-rule

1. Given the following functions and their dependencies:

$$
u(r,v,w) \\
v(r,t) \\
w(r,t)
$$

What is the chain rule expansion of $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}$$

2. Given the following functions and their dependencies:

$$
y(x,\mu,\sigma) \\
\mu(x) \\
\sigma(x,\mu)
$$

What is the chain rule expansion of $$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$$

I am stuck at writing down the first term itself. If I write $\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} \frac{\partial r}{\partial r} + \dots$, then I get $\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}$ on both sides of the equation, which is incorrect.

Comment: For the record, the derivative you describe in your post is essentially the total derivative, you just have to be careful depending on the inner variables.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{equation}
u=u(r,v(r,t),w(r,t)) \\
\end{equation}
Because $v$ and $w$ depend on $r$ you can't just take $u$'s partial derivative . Instead you need to take its total derivative w.r.t $r$:

$$\dfrac{\mathrm{du}}{\mathrm{dr}}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\underbrace{\frac{\mathrm{dr}}{\mathrm{dr}}}_{1}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial v}\frac{\mathrm{dv}}{\mathrm{dr}}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial w}\frac{\mathrm{dw}}{\mathrm{dr}}$$

$$\dfrac{\mathrm{du}}{\mathrm{dr}}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial v}\frac{\mathrm{dv}}{\mathrm{dr}}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial w}\frac{\mathrm{dw}}{\mathrm{dr}}$$

For $t$ it's a bit different since $u$ does not depend on $t$ directly:

$$\dfrac{\mathrm{du}}{\mathrm{dt}}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\underbrace{{\frac{\mathrm{dr}}{\mathrm{dt}}}}_{0}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial v}{\frac{\mathrm{du}}{\mathrm{dt}}}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial w}{\frac{\mathrm{dw}}{\mathrm{dt}}}$$

$$\dfrac{\mathrm{du}}{\mathrm{dt}}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial v}{\frac{\mathrm{dv}}{\mathrm{dt}}}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial w}{\frac{\mathrm{dw}}{\mathrm{dt}}}$$

Comment: What i meant to say is that they are the same function, it's just you didn't write out every single dependency. Of course $u$ depends on all those other stuff.

Comment: The reason you can't take the partial derivative of $f(x,y(x))$ w.r.t. $x$ is because $y$ depends on $x$ and that way you'd lose data. So you need to take its total derivative. If your function $g(x,y)$ doesn't have functions/variables that are composed within each other/depend on each other, then you can take their partial derivative.

Comment: What you are looking for is [Total derivative with direct dependencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative#Example:_Differentiation_with_indirect_dependencies), start reading this from the **Direct** part.

Comment: There is the answer to your question literally in the first paragraph: "The partial derivative of f with respect to x does not give the true rate of change of f with respect to changing x because changing x necessarily changes y" Maybe you missed this part? In your function $y$ depends on $x$. You made that precondition. These are ideas of how these variables interact. It's all written down on the wikipedia page under the two cases. Don't forget to read the last line, which i also included in my answer.